# View Controller delegate returns nil

Tags: ios, swift

My code is below. When I press the 'Done' or 'Cancel' buttons, it doesn't work as I want. I did some debugging, and `delegate` is `nil` even though I set it. Please help - thanks.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,EditViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    //页面跳转时
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EditView" {
            //通过seque的标识获得跳转目标
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! EditViewController
            //设置代理
            controller.delegate = self
            //将值传递给新页面
            controller.oldInfo = label.text
        }
    }

    func editInfo(controller:EditViewController, newInfo:String){

        label.text = newInfo
        //关闭编辑页面
        controller.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editInfoDidCancer(controller:EditViewController){

        //关闭编辑页面
        controller.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

import UIKit

protocol EditViewControllerDelegate {
    func editInfo(controller:EditViewController, newInfo:String)
    func editInfoDidCancer(controller:EditViewController)
}

class EditViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var delegate:EditViewControllerDelegate?

    var oldInfo:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if oldInfo  != nil{
            textField.text = oldInfo
        }
    }

    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.editInfo(self, newInfo: textField.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.editInfoDidCancer(self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the `prepareForSegue` method? Are you sure `delegate` is ever set? Perhaps your segue is not called `EditView`, but something slightly different?

Comment: Just noticed that you have an `editInfoDidCancer` method, presumably this should be `editInfoDidCancel`?

Comment: thanks,i tried that, delegate isn't been set. how can i solve that?

Answer (score 1):

I’m not able to tell from your code how you are handling the opening of `EditViewController` from your `ViewController`.

I’m guessing that your `prepareForSegue:sender:` **is not getting called resulting in the delegate not getting set.** To fix this, you will need to add a `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` call at the point where the segue needs to happen as in

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("EditView", sender: self)
```

You should replace whatever code is performing the opening of `EditViewController` with that call.

I have an app the uses `showViewController:sender:` to open up a second view controller from the first one even though there is a `Show` segue defined in my storyboard. The segue in my storyboard doesn’t get used in that case and `prepareForSegue:sender:` is never called as a result.

If I replace my

```
showViewController(myVC, sender: self)
```

with

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegue", sender: self)
```

then `prepareForSegue:sender:` will get called. If I am setting a delegate, like you are, in `prepareForSegue:sender:`, the delegate will get set before the segue happens.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,EditViewControllerDelegate {
var controller: EditViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    //页面跳转时
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "EditView" {
            //通过seque的标识获得跳转目标
            controller = segue.destinationViewController as! EditViewController
            //设置代理
            controller.delegate = self
            //将值传递给新页面
            controller.oldInfo = label.text
        }
    }

    func editInfo(controller:EditViewController, newInfo:String){

        label.text = newInfo
        //关闭编辑页面
        controller.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func editInfoDidCancer(controller:EditViewController){

        //关闭编辑页面
        controller.presentingViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}

import UIKit

protocol EditViewControllerDelegate {
    func editInfo(controller:EditViewController, newInfo:String)
    func editInfoDidCancer(controller:EditViewController)
}

class EditViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var delegate:EditViewControllerDelegate?

    var oldInfo:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if oldInfo  != nil{
            textField.text = oldInfo
        }
    }

    @IBAction func done(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.editInfo(self, newInfo: textField.text!)
    }

    @IBAction func cancel(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.editInfoDidCancer(self)
    }
}
```